# Add random number to script source (Blogger JSON call)

Tags: javascript, blogger, blogspot

I not at all familiar with Javascript. I have a script on Blogger for generating a link to a random post, but due to Blogger's restrictions, I can't get more than the latest 100 posts from the JSON call. I want to try to get around this by randomly assigning the starting point. The portion in question is:

```
<script src='/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=rp_results_label&amp;start-index=200'/>
```

How can I replace that 200 with a randomly generated number?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing the [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) will help with achieving what you require. Also adding `max-results=1` query parameter to the feed URL will limit the results to a single post. As we can't add Javascript variables directly in the `script` tag's src, we will have to load it via JavaScript.

```html
<script>
var ascript = document.createElement('script');
ascript.src = '/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&max-results=1&callback=rp_results_label&start-index=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(201));
ascript.async=true;
var loc = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; loc.parentNode.insertBefore(ascript, loc);
</script>
```

You can replace `201` with any integer between `1` to `(total number of published posts on the blog)+1`

Comment: That sounds great, but when I substitute the original line for your revised code, the functionality breaks.

The whole code portion is here: https://pastebin.com/DGNY29ey
I'm not smart enough to figure out why it isn't working now. I thought I added your code in correctly.

Comment: Could you share the blog URL on which this issue is happening?